# update version of application in android without missing content

Tags: android

I created an Android app. The app needs some contents (sounds, XML and ...) those user must download from internet. Now, I want to provide service for users which update app version, without losing apps content.

Could someone advice me how to do it?

Comment: If you store your current content in a database or on your SD card how it will get lost?

Comment: content to rely on app and app work with them. my question is this: if this content(download from internet) save in folder of the app, when user update app version what happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I you've ever reinstalled an app, you should have seen the dialog by PackageInstaller that says "All user data is preserved." Data you store in `SharedPreferences`, SQLite database, or SD card are just there and won't be cleared by update.

But if you want to uninstall your app before installing a new one, the only place you can store your data is SD card.

By the way, SD card is also the most appropriate place for storing downloaded files.